# SVG Path Isn't Filling Correctly - Strange Hover/Fill Behavior

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am attempting to learn [D3](https://d3js.org/) by following, and extending [Mike Bostock](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/)'s excellent [Bubble Map tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bubble-map/). At the end of his tutorial, he suggests some modifications as exercises. I've tried to implement those modifications by way of:

- A tooltip showing county name and population

  - I used the [D3-tip](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip) library for this
- Showing county lines on hover

  - I don't yet have this working. Right now, I'm drawing the county lines with `opacity: 0`, thinking I could show them later. However, I think this is a wrong approach, as I don't think I could individually refer to the paths. I suspect the `arc` property in the `json` file is what I will need to use, though I need to better understand the `topoJSON` library for this.

My questions:

- how can I make it so that when you hover over the bubble, you highlight the county line?
- how can I make it so that when you hover *inside a county*, you highlight the county line?

Here is the current version of [my Block](http://bl.ocks.org/diego898/148499eb204e7b0ea442)

**EDIT**: I've updated [my Block](http://bl.ocks.org/diego898/148499eb204e7b0ea442) with some strange hover behavior! I noticed that when I add the following CSS:

`.border--state :hover {
  fill: orange;
}`

I don't get anything, but when I change it to:

`.border--state:hover {
  fill: orange;
}`

(no space between `.border--state` and `:hover`) I get the following:

[image]

which is very strange. In addition, if I do the same thing with `.bubble`, I alternate between changing the color of *one* bubble on hover vs *all* bubbles on hover!